# AWS WAF vs google bots and other crawlers

Tags: amazon-web-services, googlebot, web-application-firewall

I deployed AWS WAF for my ALB(use cloudformation template). And now I want to configure scan probe and bad bot rules to work with google and other search bots.How can I identify "good" bots?